# Tax return on income less than 8000 USD from royalties

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, f1-student-visa

I am a U.S. Nonresident Alien (graduate student in Seattle, WA). I am married, but my wife is not in US.

In 2018, I earned ~8,000 USD in royalties. That's my total US earnings for 2018. I have not paid any taxes on it. I read that if total yearly income is less than 12,000 USD, an individual is not required to file taxes.

Do I need to file income tax in US for 2018?